# EventListener mechanism in twisted

Tags: python, design-patterns, twisted

I just wanted to hear ideas on correct usage of EventListener/EventSubscription provider in twisted. Most of the examples and the twisted source handle events through the specific methods with a pretty hard coupling. Dispatching target methods of those events are "hardcoded" in a specific Protocol class and then it is a duty of inheriting class to override these to receive the "event". This is very nice and transparent to use while we know of all of potential subscribers when creating the Protocol. 
However in larger projects there is a need (perhaps I am in a wrong mindset) for a more dynamic event subscription and subscription removal: think of hundereds of object with a lifespan of a minute all interested in the same event. 
What would be correct way to acheive this according to the "way of twisted". I currently have created an event subscription / dispatching mechanism, however there is a lingering thought that the lack of this pattern in twisted library might suggest that there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted havs a package "twisted.words.xish.utility.EventDispatcher", pydoc it to know the usage, it is simple. However, I think what make Twisted strong is its "Deferred". You can looks  Deferred object as a Closure of related events (something OK, something failed), callback, fallback are registed observer function. Deferred has advanced feature, such as can be nested.
So in my opinion, you can use default EventDispatcher in Twisted, or invent some simple new. But If you introduce some complicated mechanism into Twisted, it dooms to lead a confusion and mess.

Comment: The shortcoming I see with Deffered in this scenario is it that it by design is fired only once, and is no replacement for permanent or semi permanent event subscription. Also I know of that EventDispatcher; however I would suspect that something so trivial as EventDispatcher should be more of a core package rather than a part of a specific funcionality set. This is what raised my doubts if EventDispatchers are needed in twisted at all or is there a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: The abstract use case to better illustrate the sample would be: say I am developing a network monitoring app, where every monitored element is an actual Instance in twisted. Now every Instance should be aware of the devices it depends upon, and should be able a) upon the start of observation be able to place event listeners against events triggered by other Instances, and b) upon the end of observation to remove those listeners. This means that event wise we will have multiple-2-multiple type relationships, relationships will change in runtime and events are recurring.

Comment: IMHO, you can collect all the events to a dispather, and dispatch the events to any instance subcribe for it . There are already many dispatchers in python world, e.g. http://pubsub.sourceforge.net. In other words, event-in-function of the dipatcher is a callback of twisted mechanism. And to make things safter, you may do "dispatching" work in the end of event-in-function.

Comment: I perfectly understand the pattern of EventDispatchers / EventListeners. Perhaps I should have formulated this differently, but the actual question is: "Is there a room for this kind of pattern at all in twisted". Considering the wealth of funcionality twisted offers and the rare presence of this pattern in the framework, I somehow feel that using it in twsited context might be wrong, as there should be a better pattern for that.